# Systemd restart triggers onfailure - how do I stop this?

Tags: systemd

I have a systemd unit that has an OnFailure handler (another service).  If I use systemctl to restart the unit, then the unit is stopped which causes the OnFailure handler to run.  However the unit didn't fail - I just want to restart it and need to prevent the OnFailure from running.

```
root@device:/etc/systemd/system# systemctl restart myservice
[  159.194237] systemd[1]: Stopping myservice...
[  159.224148] systemd[1]: myservice.service: main process exited, code=killed, status=3/QUIT
[  159.224812] systemd[1]: myservice.service entered failed state.
[  159.225363] systemd[1]: Triggering OnFailure= dependencies of myservice.service.
[  159.225905] systemd[1]: Starting Handling myservice on Failure...
[  159.227664] systemd[1]: Starting myservice...
Job for myservice.service canceled.
```

OS is Debian 8 (Jessie)

Comment: Informed guesswork: the log shows `status=3/QUIT`, which means the process terminated because of an unhandled SIGQUIT. To exit successfully, it should handle the signal and terminate gracefully. Alternatively, set the `SuccessExitStatus` config option to tell systemd that other exit statuses should not count as failures.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the command in `ExecStop=` produced an error cause service entered failed state.

Comment: There is no ExecStop key.  systemd did the default which is sending a quit signal which caused the main process to quit.  Which is exactly what should happen.